# 1080Ti Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (8 vs. 0) invalid device function

Tags: caffe, pycaffe, cudnn

I got this sentence in py-faster-Rcnn

```
F0205 17:04:17.806836  4300 pooling_layer.cu:212] Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (8 vs. 0)  invalid device function
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
```

GPU : Geforce 1080Ti

CUDA : 7.5

Cudnn : v5

My Makefile.config

```
CUDA_ARCH := -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 \
        -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21 \
        -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
        -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
        -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 \
        -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 \
        -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 \
        -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 \
        -gencode arch=compute_61,code=compute_61
```

what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install CUDA 8.0 and that should resolve the issue.

From [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) you can find out that GeForce GTX 1080 Ti GPU belongs to Pascal GPU Micro architecture with compute capability version 6.1 which is supported by CUDA 8.0 or higher.

> CUDA SDK 8.0 support for compute capability 2.0 – 6.x (Fermi, Kepler, Maxwell, Pascal), last version with support for Compute Capability 2.x (Fermi)
>
> CUDA SDK 7.5 support for compute capability 2.0 – 5.x (Fermi, Kepler,
>   Maxwell)

Comment: Thanks I fixed it !!

Comment: Glad to know that you could fix it. Please 'mark answer as accepted' if it served the purpose or helped you to fix.